# how do I replace a heating element in the oven

Tags: oven

My heating element in the bottom of my oven went out. I replaced it with a new one and it doesn't get hot. Now what?

Comment: contact oven manufacturer?

Comment: move this to electrical engineering?

Comment: I actually didn't mean to migrate this without checking with Electrical Engineering first, but I did. So, I'll ask what is best to do now.

Comment: Probably gonna find more expertise over on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oven), but you're gonna need a lot more details about your oven and what you did to try & fix it before you ask there.

Comment: I'm a moderator on [diy.se]. Appliance repair is on-topic there, but to help you we'd need the make & model number of the oven, possibly the model of the replacement heating element, how you determined it was the element and not some other component, a description of what you did during the replacement, photos of the element and how it's connected, maybe other things I haven't thought of...

Answer (score 1):

I did that once and found when the first element failed , it had heated a copper spring contact and softened it so that it would not work . A new control was needed.